# Interaction with ListBox in WPF Popup does not work

Tags: wpf, listbox, popup, focus

I wanted to create a control that lets me select the unit for a value in a textbox. To archieve this i attached a button after the textbox and opened a popup on hover containing a ListBox with the available units.

If i put a button in this popup all works fine, i get a hover effect and can click the button. But the ListBox does not work as expected. Doing nothing special i´am not able to click or focus the ListBox items. Setting the FocusManager.IsFocusScope to true for the popup lets me select an item with two clicks, first to focus the window, second to focus the ListBox i suppose. Moving the focus programmatically has not helped either.

Sample Popup:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_UnitPopup" 
  PlacementTarget="{Binding}" 
  Placement="Bottom">
  <StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="PART_UnitPopupListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding,Path=Units}"/>
    <Button Content="Click me!" />
  </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

Read some things and tried some solutions with moving focus on opened or focus events of popup, but not get this work to behave in normal style like the button does. Maybe there is also another method except of popop to accomplish this task, but it seams to be a good solution and i found a bunch of code that is said to be working and does not differ much.

Comment: Sounds complicated. Why not simply use a ComboBox for selecting the unit, instead of the Button with Popup.

Comment: Its a design and usability requirement so style it this way (small simple button and popup behaviour). Thought also of manually using a window but positioning might be challeging.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that is a bit away from a real solution, but i´d like to share it.
Because buttons seams to work well i put buttons into the ListBox` item template und changed the style to make them look like flat objects. Now hover and interactions works without needing to do two clicks.

As a pitfall i´m no longer able to rely on the selection changed event, because the buttons intercept all clicks. So i added a command to the buttons that does the same work as the changed handler did before. This basically gets the work done, but other ideas would be appreciated.